# discord js dont detect messages

Tags: node.js, discord.js

so i made this code
and i don't know why my bot don't
detect any message?

```
const { Client, Intents, Channel } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client( {intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]});
const { token } = require("./config.json");
bot.once("ready",() => {
  console.log("połączony1");
  bot.user.setActivity("hej",{type: "WATCHING"})
})
bot.on('message', async msg =>  {
  console.log(msg.content);
});


bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES to your Intents. This will make bot trigger on any messages in guilds (discord servers).

Also, if you're using v13 of Discord.js, keep in mind that 'message' event has been deprecated in favour of 'messageCreate' (source: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#naming-conventions)